# How to integrate video encryption & decryption from php for Android & Ios both?

Tags: php, android, ios, encryption

I research about encryption/decryption mechanism & found many solutions like AES Encryption/Decryption. But, I want to secure my video just like videos secured in Hotstar, IMDB, Amazon Prime etc. For this I got a solution related to DRM mechanism. I understood its working process but, how it will be integrated from php side & connect it with mobile apps. Is there any other way to achieve security like apps that are mentioned above.

Comment: What is the purpose of this encryption? is this against man-in-the-middle attack? or you want some content restriction? do you want to stream videos, or download first (and then decrypt) on the client device?

Comment: I want to upload video from app to server & want to give access to only particular users. @JonnieJS

Comment: So this is an authorization mechanism, Why do you need the encryption?

Comment: The encryption is to secure video from others .i.e; if I have a video & share it to you only. Now, if you can share the same link to other person then that person will not allow to view that video. How will I get that type of mechanism? @JonnieJS

Answer (score 1):

This is not an encryption question.
It's an authorization question.

I suggest using some login mechanism. like wordpress/drupal have.

1. The first user will share the video to his friend (his friend email address)
2. The friend gets an invitation email, to register an account and watch the video.
3. The friend, register with the account, and logs in.
4. in the page "Videos shared with me" he can see videos that the original sharer, shared with this particular e-mail address. (this information comes from some database)

Now for the streaming part,

1. make sure that the folder you hold the videos is not accessible from the internet. (some other folder, higher than public_html **or** use `.htaccess` on a private folder to restrict access directly.)
2. when viewing the page "Videos shared with me" generate a link to the video that goes to your PHP controller. something like `www.mywebsite.com/watchvideo/620`
3. when someone asks this video, you check if this person is logged in, and his account has access to this video again. if so, stream the video with the php buffer. learn more about: [php output buffering](http://googl.com/#q=php+output+buffering) and stream the video using [readfile](http://php.net/readfile)

If you find this answer helpful, **consider to accept it.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciable. But, I want a flow as follows,

1.) User A will create an account from app & upload video from app. 

2.) Now, User A will share the video to User B from the app (email address of User B). But it's not necessary for User B to have an account in app. 

3.) When User B clicks that link from email, he will first asked for authentication(Password or any other key), after entering the valid password User B can able to stream that video for limited time span.